# How to view or plot a decision tree for the Tree Structure in this example?

Tags: matlab

I have a code for ID3 decision tree but I cannot find the appropriate code for plotting or viewing the Tree

I have used several view MATLAB functions like `view(Mdl,'Mode','graph')` but none of them worked the code currently  produces result of decision tree structure as

```
DECISION TREE STRUCTURE:
parent: root    attribute: IsRich   falseChild:HasScholarship   trueChild:GoodLetters
parent: IsRich  attribute: HasScholarship   falseChild:false    trueChild:GoodSAT
parent: HasScholarship  false
parent: HasScholarship  attribute: GoodSAT  falseChild:false    trueChild:GoodLetters
parent: GoodSAT false
parent: GoodSAT attribute: GoodLetters  falseChild:false    trueChild:true
parent: GoodLetters false
parent: GoodLetters true
parent: IsRich  attribute: GoodLetters  falseChild:GoodGrades   trueChild:GoodGrades
parent: GoodLetters attribute: GoodGrades   falseChild:false    trueChild:SchoolActivities
parent: GoodGrades  false
parent: GoodGrades  attribute: SchoolActivities falseChild:false    trueChild:true
parent: SchoolActivities    false
parent: SchoolActivities    true
parent: GoodLetters attribute: GoodGrades   falseChild:GoodSAT  trueChild:true
parent: GoodGrades  attribute: GoodSAT  falseChild:false    trueChild:true
parent: GoodSAT false
parent: GoodSAT true
parent: GoodGrades  true
```

So I would like to plot this Tree Structure , any help will much appreciated

```
% ID3 Decision Tree Algorithm

function[] = decisiontree(inputFileName, trainingSetSize, numberOfTrials,...
                          verbose)
% DECISIONTREE Create a decision tree by following the ID3 algorithm
% args:
%   inputFileName       - the fully specified path to input file
%   trainingSetSize     - integer specifying number of examples from input
%                         used to train the dataset
%   numberOfTrials      - integer specifying how many times decision tree
%                         will be built from a randomly selected subset
%                         of the training examples
%   verbose             - string that must be eiher '1' or '0', if '1'
%                         output includes training and test sets, else
%                         it will only contain description of tree and
%                         results for the trials

% Read in the specified text file contain the examples
fid = fopen(inputFileName, 'rt');
dataInput = textscan(fid, '%s');
% Close the file
fclose(fid);

% Reformat the data into attribute array and data matrix of 1s and 0s for
% true or false
i = 1;
% First store the attributes into a cell array
while (~strcmp(dataInput{1}{i}, 'CLASS'));
    i = i + 1;
end
attributes = cell(1,i);
for j=1:i;
    attributes{j} = dataInput{1}{j};
end

% NOTE: The classification will be the final attribute in the data rows
% below
numAttributes = i;
numInstances = (length(dataInput{1}) - numAttributes) / numAttributes;
% Then store the data into matrix
data = zeros(numInstances, numAttributes);
i = i + 1;
for j=1:numInstances
    for k=1:numAttributes
        data(j, k) = strcmp(dataInput{1}{i}, 'true');
        i = i + 1;
    end
end

% Here is where the trials start
for i=1:numberOfTrials;

    % Print the trial number
    fprintf('TRIAL NUMBER: %d\n\n', i);

    % Split data into training and testing sets randomly
    % Use randsample to get a vector of row numbers for the training set
    rows = sort(randsample(numInstances, trainingSetSize));
    % Initialize two new matrices, training set and test set
    trainingSet = zeros(trainingSetSize, numAttributes);
    testingSetSize = (numInstances - trainingSetSize);
    testingSet = zeros(testingSetSize, numAttributes);
    % Loop through data matrix, copying relevant rows to each matrix
    training_index = 1;
    testing_index = 1;
    for data_index=1:numInstances;
        if (rows(training_index) == data_index);
            trainingSet(training_index, :) = data(data_index, :);
            if (training_index < trainingSetSize);
                training_index = training_index + 1;
            end
        else
            testingSet(testing_index, :) = data(data_index, :);
            if (testing_index < testingSetSize);
                testing_index = testing_index + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    % If verbose, print out training set
    if (verbose);
        for ii=1:numAttributes;
            fprintf('%s\t', attributes{ii});
        end
        fprintf('\n');
        for ii=1:trainingSetSize;
            for jj=1:numAttributes;
                if (trainingSet(ii, jj));
                    fprintf('%s\t', 'true');
                else
                    fprintf('%s\t', 'false');
                end
            end
            fprintf('\n');
        end
    end

    % Estimate the expected prior probability of TRUE and FALSE based on
    % training set
    if (sum(trainingSet(:, numAttributes)) >= trainingSetSize);
        expectedPrior = 'true';
    else
        expectedPrior = 'false';
    end

    % Construct a decision tree on the training set using the ID3 algorithm
    activeAttributes = ones(1, length(attributes) - 1);
    new_attributes = attributes(1:length(attributes)-1);
    tree = ID3(trainingSet, attributes, activeAttributes);  % Here ID3 function

    % Print out the tree
    fprintf('DECISION TREE STRUCTURE:\n');
    PrintTree(tree, 'root');


end
```

The ID3 function is

```
function [tree] = ID3(examples, attributes, activeAttributes)
% ID3   Runs the ID3 algorithm on the matrix of examples and attributes
% args:
%       examples            - matrix of 1s and 0s for trues and falses, the
%                             last value in each row being the value of the
%                             classifying attribute
%       attributes          - cell array of attribute strings (no CLASS)
%       activeAttributes    - vector of 1s and 0s, 1 if corresponding attr.
%                             active (no CLASS)
% return:
%       tree                - the root node of a decision tree
% tree struct:
%       value               - will be the string for the splitting
%                             attribute, or 'true' or 'false' for leaf
%       left                - left pointer to another tree node (left means
%                             the splitting attribute was false)
%       right               - right pointer to another tree node (right
%                             means the splitting attribute was true)

if (isempty(examples));
    error('Must provide examples');
end

% Constants
numberAttributes = length(activeAttributes);
numberExamples = length(examples(:,1));

% Create the tree node
tree = struct('value', 'null', 'left', 'null', 'right', 'null');

% If last value of all rows in examples is 1, return tree labeled 'true'
lastColumnSum = sum(examples(:, numberAttributes + 1));
if (lastColumnSum == numberExamples);
    tree.value = 'true';
    return
end
% If last value of all rows in examples is 0, return tree labeled 'false'
if (lastColumnSum == 0);
    tree.value = 'false';
    return
end
% If activeAttributes is empty, then return tree with label as most common
% value
if (sum(activeAttributes) == 0);
    if (lastColumnSum >= numberExamples / 2);
        tree.value = 'true';
    else
        tree.value = 'false';
    end
    return
end

% Find the current entropy
p1 = lastColumnSum / numberExamples;
if (p1 == 0);
    p1_eq = 0;
else
    p1_eq = -1*p1*log2(p1);
end
p0 = (numberExamples - lastColumnSum) / numberExamples;
if (p0 == 0);
    p0_eq = 0;
else
    p0_eq = -1*p0*log2(p0);
end
currentEntropy = p1_eq + p0_eq;
% Find the attribute that maximizes information gain
gains = -1*ones(1,numberAttributes); %-1 if inactive, gains for all else 
% Loop through attributes updating gains, making sure they are still active
for i=1:numberAttributes;
    if (activeAttributes(i)) % this one is still active, update its gain
        s0 = 0; s0_and_true = 0;
        s1 = 0; s1_and_true = 0;
        for j=1:numberExamples;
            if (examples(j,i)); % this instance has splitting attr. true
                s1 = s1 + 1;
                if (examples(j, numberAttributes + 1)); %target attr is true
                    s1_and_true = s1_and_true + 1;
                end
            else
                s0 = s0 + 1;
                if (examples(j, numberAttributes + 1)); %target attr is true
                    s0_and_true = s0_and_true + 1;
                end
            end
        end

        % Entropy for S(v=1)
        if (~s1);
            p1 = 0;
        else
            p1 = (s1_and_true / s1); 
        end
        if (p1 == 0);
            p1_eq = 0;
        else
            p1_eq = -1*(p1)*log2(p1);
        end
        if (~s1);
            p0 = 0;
        else
            p0 = ((s1 - s1_and_true) / s1);
        end
        if (p0 == 0);
            p0_eq = 0;
        else
            p0_eq = -1*(p0)*log2(p0);
        end
        entropy_s1 = p1_eq + p0_eq;

        % Entropy for S(v=0)
        if (~s0);
            p1 = 0;
        else
            p1 = (s0_and_true / s0); 
        end
        if (p1 == 0);
            p1_eq = 0;
        else
            p1_eq = -1*(p1)*log2(p1);
        end
        if (~s0);
            p0 = 0;
        else
            p0 = ((s0 - s0_and_true) / s0);
        end
        if (p0 == 0);
            p0_eq = 0;
        else
            p0_eq = -1*(p0)*log2(p0);
        end
        entropy_s0 = p1_eq + p0_eq;

        gains(i) = currentEntropy - ((s1/numberExamples)*entropy_s1) - ((s0/numberExamples)*entropy_s0);
    end
end

% Pick the attribute that maximizes gains
[~, bestAttribute] = max(gains);
% Set tree.value to bestAttribute's relevant string
tree.value = attributes{bestAttribute};
% Remove splitting attribute from activeAttributes
activeAttributes(bestAttribute) = 0;

% Initialize and create the new example matrices
examples_0 = []; examples_0_index = 1;
examples_1 = []; examples_1_index = 1;
for i=1:numberExamples;
    if (examples(i, bestAttribute)); % this instance has it as 1/true
        examples_1(examples_1_index, :) = examples(i, :); % copy over
        examples_1_index = examples_1_index + 1;
    else
        examples_0(examples_0_index, :) = examples(i, :);
        examples_0_index = examples_0_index + 1;
    end
end

% For both values of the splitting attribute
% For value = false or 0, corresponds to left branch
% If examples_0 is empty, add leaf node to the left with relevant label
if (isempty(examples_0));
    leaf = struct('value', 'null', 'left', 'null', 'right', 'null');
    if (lastColumnSum >= numberExamples / 2); % for matrix examples
        leaf.value = 'true';
    else
        leaf.value = 'false';
    end
    tree.left = leaf;
else
    % Here is were we can recur
    tree.left = ID3(examples_0, attributes, activeAttributes);
end
% For value = true or 1, corresponds to right branch
% If examples_1 is empty, add leaf node to the right with relevant label
if (isempty(examples_1));
    leaf = struct('value', 'null', 'left', 'null', 'right', 'null');
    if (lastColumnSum >= numberExamples / 2); % for matrix examples
        leaf.value = 'true';
    else
        leaf.value = 'false';
    end
    tree.right = leaf;
else
    % Here is were we can recur
    tree.right = ID3(examples_1, attributes, activeAttributes);
end

% Now we can return tree
return
end
```

PrintTree.m

```
function [] = PrintTree(tree, parent)
% Prints the tree structure (preorder traversal)

% Print current node
if (strcmp(tree.value, 'true'));
    fprintf('parent: %s\ttrue\n', parent);

    return
elseif (strcmp(tree.value, 'false'));
    fprintf('parent: %s\tfalse\n', parent);

    return
else
    % Current node an attribute splitter
    fprintf('parent: %s\tattribute: %s\tfalseChild:%s\ttrueChild:%s\n', ...
        parent, tree.value, tree.left.value, tree.right.value);

end

% Recur the left subtree
PrintTree(tree.left, tree.value);

% Recur the right subtree
PrintTree(tree.right, tree.value);
%treeplot(node)
end
```

Comment: Where do you get the `ID3` function from? Is there any documentation for it? If you can't dig inside it, you'll have to parse the text output yourself. Look at [`textscan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for parsing the text and [`digraph`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) to build a tree structure that you can then `plot`.

Comment: @nekomatic I added the ID3 function in the edit above

Comment: OK so the `ID3` function returns a struct representing the tree and the `PrintTree` function turns that into text. Do you have the code for `PrintTree`? I would look at modifying that so that it generates either a `digraph` object as it goes along, or an adjacency matrix that you can use to create a `digraph`.

Comment: @nekomatic I have included the PrintTree.m function on the edit above , and I have tried to use it to generate a treeplot but have not succeeded any help will be so much obliged

Comment: Where did you get the syntax `view(Mdl,'Mode','graph')` from? The documentation to the `view` function doesn't mention anything like that at all.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry!, the code was not supposed to be there I have removed it, it was one of my  attempt to build the tree diagram but it did not work

Comment: The whole implementation of the code with sample data can be found here -> https://github.com/gwheaton/ID3-Decision-Tree

Comment: The Implementation code works fine, but it does not plot the tree, that is the only thing I am looking and struggling for

Comment: @CrisLuengo `view(tree, 'mode', 'graph')` can be used to plot a [Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/view-decision-tree.html) classification or regression tree object, but obviously that's not what the OP's code generates.

Comment: @nekomatic: Really? That sounds like a really bad design decision! Overloading a function to do something completely different and unrelated? What were they thinking???